# Cant show old value and edit value in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

How to show an old value / query field from database in mysql, and edit value in Laravel. I'm using Laravel 9x and PHP 8x

Controller.php :

```html
public function edit(Business $business)
    {
        return view('dashboard.bisnis.edit', [
            'item' => $business
        ]);
    }
    
public function update(Request $request, Business $business)
    {
        $rules  = [
            'deskripsi' => 'required|max:255',
            'pemilik' => 'required|max:255'
        ];

        $validateData = $request->validate($rules);

        Business::where('id', $business->id)->update($validateData);

        return redirect('/dashboard/bisnis')->with('success', 'Item has been updated !');
    }
```

Blade.php:

```html
@extends('dashboard.index')

@section('container')

<div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
    <h1 class="h2">Edit Data Bisnis</h1>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-8">
    <form method="post" action="/dashboard/bisnis/{{ $item->id }}" class="mb-5" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @method('put')
        @csrf

        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="deskripsi" class="form-label">Deskripsi</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control @error('deskripsi') is-invalid @enderror" id="deskripsi" name="deskripsi" required autofocus
          value="{{ old('deskripsi', $item->deskripsi) }}">
          @error('deskripsi')
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ $message }}
          </div>
          @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="pemilik" class="form-label">Pemilik</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control @error('pemilik') is-invalid @enderror" id="pemilik" name="pemilik" required autofocus
          value="{{ old('pemilik', $item->pemilik) }}">
          @error('pemilik')
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ $message }}
          </div>
          @enderror
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan Perubahan</button>
    </form>
</div>
    
<script>
  const deskripsi = document.querySelector('#deskripsi');
  const pemilik = document.querySelector('#pemilik');
</script>

@endsection
```

Also when navigating through my menu such as Business, the sidebar seems cant to be clicked, nor use. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is i forgot to pass my $id on my controller and route (web.php). Here's my route

```html
Route::controller(GroupServiceController::class)->middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard/gruplayanan', 'index');
    Route::get('/dashboard/gruplayanan/create', 'create')->name('gruplayanan.create');
    Route::post('/dashboard/gruplayanan', 'store')->name('gruplayanan.store');
    Route::get('/dashboard/gruplayanan/edit/{id}', 'edit')->name('gruplayanan.edit');
    Route::post('/dashboard/gruplayanan/update/{id}', 'update')->name('gruplayanan.update');
    Route::post('/dashboard/gruplayanan/delete/{id}', 'destroy')->name('gruplayanan.delete');
});
```

and my controller :

```html
public function edit(GroupService $groupService, $id)
    {
        $groupService = $groupService->findOrFail($id);

        return view('dashboard.gruplayanan.edit', [
            'item' => $groupService
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

```
{{ old('deskripsi') ? old('deskripsi') :$item->deskripsi }}
```

Please replace this:

```
return redirect('/dashboard/bisnis')->with('success', 'Item has been updated !');
```

to

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Item has been updated !');
```

Comment: Thanks, i've tried it and didn't work either

Comment: Please try only this
{{ old('deskripsi') }}

Comment: Please check and replace this and try again:

{{ old('deskripsi') ? old('deskripsi') :$item->deskripsi }}


return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Item has been updated !');

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use Laravel 9

Referring to [Repopulating Forms - Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#repopulating-forms)

Controller.php:

you should use

```
$deskripsi = $request->old('deskripsi');
$pemilik = $request->old('pemilik');
```

before

```
$validateData = $request->validate($rules);
```

Blade.php:

you should use this on input

```
value="{{ old('deskripsi') }}"
value="{{ old('pemilik') }}"
```

By default **old** will return null if no input exists so we don't need to use nullcheck like

```
{{old('deskripsi') ?? ''}}
```

Comment: where to declare the $deskripsi and $pemilik ?

Answer (score 0):

To repopulate value using [`old()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#repopulating-forms) in Laravel you need to return a response [**`withInput()`**](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#old-input). Not just response.

The return code should

```
return redirect('/dashboard/bisnis')->with('success', 'Item has been updated !');
```

change to this

```
return redirect('/dashboard/bisnis')->with('success', 'Item has been updated !')->withInput();
```

Comment: I get an error says 'The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.'

Comment: It's a different issue/question. For help show me your route code. of both update and redirect

Comment: resources
└views
  └dashboard
    └ bisnis
       └create.blade.php
       └edit.blade.php
       └main.blade.php

Comment: edit your question

Comment: Yes, i've forgot to pass the $id on my route and controller

Comment: @ProgrammerWannabe, your question is about *Cant show old value and edit value in PHP Laravel*. So answered according to that.